# Angular material cannot load in my page angular what wrong with my code?

Tags: angular, angular-material

i tried angular and i had been add angular material but when i import the code my material cannot load that my screen shoot, in my app module ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CariapaComponent } from './cariapa/cariapa.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CariapaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in my app component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'appcekharga';
}
```

and my component.html

```
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <button mat-button>Basic</button>
     <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
        <button mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
    <button mat-raised-button disabled>Disabled</button>
    <a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[view of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Vax.png)

Comment: Did you imported Material css as well?

Comment: run `ng add @angular/material` in terminal  and see

Comment: Thank it Work add material